# Diophantine equation $x^2+n y^2 = b$ : when does it have solutions?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratics

recently I had to solve some diophantine equations in the form 
 $x^2 + n y^2 = b $ in the variables $x$ and $y$, for various fixed values of $n$, and  $b$.

Other than "bruteforcing" it, are there some ways to know if, given $n$ and $b$,  this equation has at least a solution?

Edit: $n$ and $b$ are both positive integers

Comment: Brute forcing is quick enough conditional if you use continuous fractions.

Comment: Are $n$ and $b$ necessarily integers as well?

Comment: @StanTendijck Thank you for your comment! Can you give me some more details/reference?

Comment: @XYZT Yes, they must be positive integers... I will edit my question

Comment: I would write it out for you but I'm actually on holiday :p Michel Waldschmidt
"Diophantine approximations and
continued fractions"

Comment: @StanTendijck ahahah, thank you!

Comment: That paper also provides the theory necessary to find integer roots. If you are just interested in the existence of roots which you actually do not specify but I just assumed that, that will always work if $b\geq0$.

Comment: Brute forcing takes a lot of work for $n=61$ and $b=1$: the [smallest solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_smallest_solution_of_Pell_equations) is $x= 1766319049$, $y=2261539804$.

Comment: @lhf    I think you are referring to the Pell's equation! Here we have + sign, instead of -

Comment: you can set $x=y+k$ and transform your equation into a simple quadratic depending on only one parameter $k$ for a given $(n,b)$.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity), it is enough to answer the question for $b$ prime.
But then the answer depends on the [arithmetic of quadratic fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer).
The answer is not simple but it is fascinating. See the book [*Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$*](https://dacox.people.amherst.edu/primes.html), by David Cox.

A good introduction is the case $n=1$, which is solved by [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) .

Comment: Of course, the role of the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity should not be misunderstood as saying that $b$ is represented by $x^2+ny^2$ iff its prime divisors are.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the Brahmagupta identity, it will be surely useful in the future... Unfortunately it does not  solve my question as @punctureddusk pointed out.

Comment: @punctureddusk, good point!

Comment: @lhf I think this answer would benefit from correcting (or just qualifying) the claim in the first line that the problem reduces to the case of prime $b$.