# The diophantine equation $N = a^2 + k \cdot b^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

There is a known theorem which solves the problem of when
a natural number can be represented as a sum of two squares.

https://archive.org/details/ElementaryNumberTheory/page/n145/mode/2up

I wonder if there's anything similar for the more general form:

$$N = a^2 + k \cdot b^2$$

If $k$ is a fixed positive integer (e.g. 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...)
when can an integer $N$ be written in this form?

Could someone point me to some useful theory about this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornacchia%27s_algorithm

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Primes-Form-ny2-Multiplication-Mathematics/dp/1118390180/

Comment: @AnginaSeng Thanks a lot! I will take a look. If you know of other resources, or related theory please point me to those too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3348387/diophantine-equation-x2n-y2-b-when-does-it-have-solutions